# warnings while running code in xilinx

Tags: verilog, xilinx, synthesis

In the following code: First, I am loading ROM with data and weight at given address. In the same clock I am doing multiplication of data and weight. Finally, I am extending the number of bits from 16-bit to 23-bit. The code compiles without errors but has warnings. I am unable to solve these warnings.

```
module main_module(extended_out,mux_out,data,weight,clk,en,addr);
input clk,en;
input [2:0] addr;
output [7:0] data,weight;
output [15:0] mux_out;
output [22:0] extended_out;

ram_input a1 (clk, en, addr, data);
ram_weight a2 (clk, en, addr, weight);
top_module a3 (mux_out,data,weight);
SignExtender a4 (clk,mux_out,extended_out);

endmodule
```

**###################    MODULE 1 ########################################**

```
module ram_input (clk, en, addr, data);
 input clk;
 input en;
 input [2:0] addr;
 output reg [7:0] data;

 reg   [2:0] raddr;
 always @(posedge clk)
 begin
    if (en)
         raddr <= addr;
 end

 always @(raddr,en) 
 begin
    if (en)
    begin
       case(raddr)
         3'b000: data = 8'b0000_0010;
         3'b001: data = 8'b0000_0110;
         3'b010: data = 8'b0000_1110;
         3'b011: data = 8'b0000_0010;
         3'b100: data = 8'b0000_0100;
         3'b101: data = 8'b0000_1010;
         3'b110: data = 8'b0000_1100;
         3'b111: data = 8'b0000_0000;
         default: data = 8'b0000_XXXX;
       endcase
    end  
    else
       data = 8'b0000_0000;
 end

endmodule
```

**####################################### MODULE 2 ########################**

```
module ram_weight (clk, en, addr, weight);
 input clk;
 input en;
 input [2:0] addr;
 output reg [7:0] weight;

 reg   [2:0] raddr;
 always @(posedge clk)
 begin
    if (en)
       raddr <= addr;
 end

 always @(raddr,en) 
 begin
    if (en)
    begin
       case(raddr)
          3'b000: weight = 8'b0000_1000;
          3'b001: weight = 8'b0000_1010;
          3'b010: weight = 8'b0001_1101;
          3'b011: weight = 8'b0001_0100;
          3'b100: weight = 8'b0000_0111;
          3'b101: weight = 8'b0001_0010;
          3'b110: weight = 8'b0010_1000;
          3'b111: weight = 8'b0011_1111;
          default: weight = 8'b0000_XXXX;
       endcase
    end
    else
       weight = 8'b0000_0000;
 end

endmodule
```

**############################33  MODULE--3 #####################**

```
module top_module(p,x,y); 
 output [15:0]p;
 input [7:0]x,y;
 reg [15:0]p;

 reg [15:0]a;
 integer i; 

 always @(x , y)
 begin
    a=x;
    p=0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
    begin
       if(y[i])
          p=p+a;
       a=a<<1;
    end
 end

endmodule
```

**############################## MOdule ----4  #############################**

```
module SignExtender( clk, extend, extended );
 input[15:0] extend;
 input clk;
 output[22:0] extended;
 reg[22:0] extended;
 wire [15:0] extend;

 always @( posedge clk)
 begin
    extended[22:0] <= { {7{extend[15]}}, extend[15:0] };
 end

endmodule
```

**###############################  ERROR   ####################**

WARNING 646 - Signal "a" is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING 1710 - "FF/Latch a4/extended_15" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block main_module. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other ""FF/Latch trimming"", FF/Latch ""a4/extended_14"" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block "main_module". This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch ""a4/extended_13"" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block ""main_module"". This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch ""a4/extended_12"" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block ""main_module"". This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch ""a4/extended_11"" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block ""main_module"". This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch ""a4/extended_10"" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block ""main_module"". This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch ""a4/extended_0"" (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block ""main_module"". This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

warning--1 says you didn't use constant "a" variable but while doing multiplication I took as an temporary register but remaining errors I don't understand what they really going to tell...

Please help explain these warnings.

Comment: Does everything work correctly when you simulate this design? If you haven't run a simulation then you should do that now and then come back and tell us the results.

Comment: I recommend to use pastebin or github for long snippet code. It's hard to see without colours.

Comment: yes sir i already simulated and output is also coming but problem with warning because while implementing this code in fpga board i don't known weather my out will come or not.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is probably the `p=p+a` in `top_module`. This doesn't make sense; try to draw the schematic. This is a combinatorial path with the output of an adder fed back to its input. Get rid of it, and just add together the [image], depending on the relevant bit of `y`. This may be enough to get you going.

**EDIT**

Your code is unlikely to be (correctly) synthesisable (by any sane synthesiser, anyway). Consider this:

```
always @(x , y)
 begin
    a=x;
    p=0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
    begin
       if(y[i])
          p=p+a;
       a=a<<1;
    end
 end
```

This is combinatorial code. You are asking the synthesiser to *unroll* your `i` loop. Every time `x` or `y` changes, you want the synthesiser to evaluate all 8 loop iterations, shifting `a`, and accumulating to `p`. Synthesisers are normally pretty good at loop unrolling, but this one is pushing it. Get rid of the loop, whether or not you think XST understands it; it's just bad practice, and is probably confusing XST. Draw a schematic on paper. All you're doing is shifting `a`: you've got one unmodified `a`, and 7 instances where `a` is shifted by 1 to 7 bits. You need an adder which adds together all 8 busses, *but* you only add in bus *i* if the corresponding bit of `y` is set. In other words, each input to the adder has a multiplexer on it; one input is held to zero, the other is your shifted `a`. You'll need to write the code yourself. This is how you do hardware design: break everything down into basic units - multiplexers, shifters, adders, whatever, and wire them togehter. Don't write behavioural code that your synthesiser has to try to work out for you; that's software, not hardware.

Greg may be right in that your actual circuit can be simplified according to your actual input conditions, and that this circuit is eventually unused anyway; it's not a 5-minute job to confirm that, and it's pointless anyway. You're trying to write a multiplier, and your input conditions will change, and you need to get the code right. XST may, or may not, be able to work out that in any particular situation it can simplify the logic, but you have to fix your input code first.

You have other issues. Don't assign X's to your variables as Don't Cares. This is very bad practice, and will go wrong. Read [Mike Turpin's paper](http://www.arm.com/files/pdf/Verilog_X_Bugs.pdf), among others. In short, never use X's unless you know exactly what you're doing. Use non-blocking assignments in the `x`/`y` always block. There may be other issues, which aren't obvious on a very quick read-through.

Comment: """""Get rid of it, and just add together the enter image description here, depending on the relevant bit of y""""""""i am not getting little bit confuse the image is clear the weight and input stored in rom is an input to multipier.....and output of it is going to sign extension,,,,,,'and i got combinational path but any solution to remove this path in this code

Answer (score 1):

The warnings are caused by the synthesizer informing you that the generated netlist does not match your RTL but is functionally equivalent. For beginner FPGA designers the warning can somewhat be ignored, but they should learn how to resolve the warnings. IC designers almost always resolve the warning because it can make [ECO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_Change_Order)s even more difficult, among other issues. The optimizer in your synthesizer tool is recognizing that bits `extended[0]` and `extended[15:10]` have a zero percent change of having a value other than `0`. It also decided that `a` is not necessary.

`extended[0]` can only be `0` because `data[0]` is only assigned to an even number. Any whole number multiplied by an even number is always even, thus the LSB will always be zero. The logic and flop/latch used to calculate this bit can safely be replaced with a `0` driver.

Similar optimization is happening for bits `extended[15:10]`. The largest value `extended` can have is `16'b0000_0001_1110_0000`; `8'b0000_1100`(data) times `8'b0010_1000`(weight) when the clocked `addr==3'b110`. Within the available values of `data` and `weight` there is no possible combination that any bit greater than 9 can be anything except `0`. Like bit 0, the synthesizer decided to save space and improve performance rather than follow your code verbatim. Most likely somewhere in the synthesis log there are warnings that bits `extended[22:16]` are also being trimmed during the optimization process.

The warning for `a` is not because it is a temporary variable. The optimizer recognizes `extended` can only be one of eight possible values. The values of `data` and `weight` values are derived from look-up tables that use the same index pointer (`addr`). Once again, it takes less logic and better performance to hard code the 8 values into another look-up table then the actual multiplication logic. With the multiplier logic no longer necessary, `a` becomes useless and is removed.

Try [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your RTL. Also make sure names of modules and nets make sense; ex `top_module` to `multiplier_8bit` and `ram_*` to `rom_*`. Consolidate redundant logic and more concise functional logic. You can ignore the warnings if you just want that mostly works. If you want to become a good logic designer, then you should try to resolve the warnings.

Comment: but while generating netlist it is showing error the code is not synthesizable

Comment: Your provided example only shows warnings. It synthesizes with out errors here http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/683  Make sure it simulates correctly before trying to synthesize.